How can i fully make navigation bar transparent in jetpack compose?
i wanna ask about how can make Navigation bar became fully transparent, i've already tried many solution but so far all i can get is my navigation bar become white and still cropping small part of the UI at the bottom like this.
and this is my current code that i use


Please [edit] your question and replace the screenshot with the code as text so we can easily copy&paste it.

To ensure its functionality, you need to apply setDecorFitsSystemWindows.
SideEffect {
    val window = (localView.context as Activity).window
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
    window.navigationBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
}


I'm late but try adding this to your MainActivity.kt on the onCreate function
val lightTransparentStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
    scrim = TRANSPARENT,
    darkScrim = TRANSPARENT
)
enableEdgeToEdge(
    statusBarStyle = lightTransparentStyle,
    navigationBarStyle = lightTransparentStyle
)

This way should work and now you should see both navigation and status bar fully transparent.
